# Python: List item is empty, code to detect if it is and then put in a place holder value?

Tags: python, list, broadcast, mit-scratch

Hey I'm writing a program that receives a broadcast from Scratch and then determines based on the broadcast, where to proceed. The code turns the broadcast(list item) into a string and then breaks that string into a list using .split(). The only problem is the broadcast may only be 1 word instead of 2. Is there a way to check if one of the list items from .split() is empty and then change it to a place holder value?

**Where I am having trouble**

```
scratchbroadcast =  str(msg[1])

    BroadcastList = scratchbroadcast.split()

    #starts the switch statement that interprets the message and proceeds
    #to the appropriate action
    v = BroadcastList[0]
    w = BroadcastList[1]
    if BroadcastList[1] == '':
        w = "na"
```

Comment: In future, please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - most of that code is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `BroadcastList` contains only one word then `BroadcastList` will be a single-element list, e.g.

```
>>> "foo".split()
['foo']
```

Obviously we can't check whether the second item in the list is an empty string `''`; **there isn't a second element**. Instead, check the *length* of the list:

```
w = "na" if len(BroadcastList) == 1 else BroadcastList[1]
```

Alternatively, use `try` to catch the `IndexError` (it's [easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-eafp)):

```
try:
    w = BroadcastList[1]
except IndexError:
    w = "na"
```

Comment: Thank you so much your first solution worked perfectly! Sorry about the wall of code, very new here and wasn't sure how much to put.

Comment: @Stickygrenade provide just enough for others to replicate the problem, and describe exactly what that problem is (you never mention `IndexError`, where you should be providing the full traceback).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first consider this: how about the third item? Or the fourth? Or the forty-second?

If the string doesn't contain a splitter character (e.g. a space), you wouldn't end up with a list of two items, one of which blank -- you would end up with a list of only one item.

In Python, the length of something is generally obtained through the built-in `len()` function:

```
len([])              # == 0
len(["foo"])         # == 1
len(["foo", "bar"])  # == 2
```

Therefore, you would do:

```
if len(broadcast_list) == 1:
    broadcast_list += [""]
```

Other ways of doing the same thing include `broadcast_list.append("")` and `broadcast_list.extend([""])`. Which one to use is completely up to you; `+=` and `.extend` are more or less equivalent while `.append` can only add a single element.

Looking at the rest of your code, your `case` calls won't work like you expect them to: in Python, strings are truthy, so `'string' or 'otherString'` is basically the same as `True or True`. `or` is strictly a boolean operator and you can't use it for 'either this or that'.

Python is notorious for not having a switch statement. Your attempt at implementing one would actually be kind of cute had you gone through with it -- something like that can be a pretty good exercise in Python OOP and passing functions as first-class objects. (In my day-to-day use of Python I hardly ever need to do something like that, but it's great to have it in your conceptual toolkit.)

You might be happy to learn that Python strings have a `lower` method; with it, your code would end up looking something like this:

```
v = broadcast_list[0].lower()
if v == 'pilight':
    # ...
else if v == 'motor':
    # ...
else if v == 'camera':
    # ....
```

On a side note, you might want to have a look a [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which is the de facto standard for formatting Python code. If you want other people to be able to quickly figure out your code, you should conform at least to its most basic propositions - such as classes being CamelCased and variables in lowercase, rather than the other way around.

Comment: Also, @jonrsharpe's comment features a couple of great Python idioms you might want to make yourself familiar with :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean about the switch statement implementation :s it works fine for me. As for the or I did a double take and thank you for that.